# SCCM Windows Update do not apply outside of Maintenance windows after deadline is reached

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012, system-center, sccm-2012-r2, sccm-2007

I have a collection with Maintenance Window of 2 AM to 4 AM. I am pushing windows updated with deadline behavior "When the installation deadline is reached, allow the following activities to be performed outside the maintenance window."

- Option "Software updates installation" is checked.
- and Option "System restart (if necessary)" unchecked.

What I was expecting to happen was to install windows updates after the deadline reaches, regardless of the maintenance windows but hold the reboots until maintenance windows.

What is happening right now is, my updates get stuck in progress mode with a message "Waiting for maintenance window before installing"

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had "All devices as part of the same group" option checked under Collection Properties > General tab. As soon as I unchecked it my software update started to flow. Now I am working maintenance window so my server only reboots during the maintenance window.